# Is there a way to keep your app icons sorted by name in LaunchPad?

Tags: macos, launchpad

It seems that LaunchPad is not remembering the position of my app icons. I manually sorted them by name, but every now and then it will shuffle them.

I have not yet identified the pattern that resets the icons (my best guess is that it is after every restart). I have also not identified the pattern on which it resets the icons themselves, but it seems to leave Apple's own apps grouped together, followed by my Mac App Store purchases at the bottom.

Is anybody else experiencing this behavior and is there a way to keep all icons sorted by name? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known bug and has been filed with Apple. All we can do is wait on a fix.

The database gets corrupted when a new entry is added and moved.

The only current workaround is to delete the database and start over, but bear in mind that once a new item is added and moved to a different position, the corruption will occur again.

The database is located in `~/Library/Application Support/Dock`

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. Do you happen to have a link to the bug report the Apple Developer site?

Comment: They don't actually have a public trac unfortunately. All I can give you is that I received a bug confirmation from an Apple engineer so it has been filed that we can be sure of. Apple is quite secretive and makes us sign confidentiality agreements so it's not something I can go into, unfortunately. That's the best I can do. They know about it that's for sure. The fact it's not been fixed yet makes me thinks it's a complex problem.

Comment: I am experiencing this in 10.7.3. This bug still needs to be fixed.

Comment: @gentmatt Yes, me too unfortunately. I could file it again, but that would only waste their time having to file a dupe. They know about it. Why they have chosen not to do anything is beyond me (maybe the issue is proving difficult to isolate). I would say this should be high priority. Imagine if your iPhone's home screen icons were shifting around!