# How do I stop Launchpad from changing app/folder order?

Tags: macos, launchpad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to keep your app icons sorted by name in LaunchPad?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28266/is-there-a-way-to-keep-your-app-icons-sorted-by-name-in-launchpad)

How do I stop Launchpad from changing the app/folder order that I set?

I have quite a few applications, so I organize most of them into folders, then I arrange the folders alphabetically to make them easier for me to access.  Then, inside the folders I usually arrange the applications alphabetically for the same reason.

Trouble is, I'll come back later and things have been rearranged on me!  Not necessarily every time, but often enough to be annoying.  (After all, the computer is supposed to do what I tell it, not the other way around!)

Is there some other step I should be taking?

Answer (score 1):

You're not the [first one to have this problem](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28266/is-there-a-way-to-keep-your-app-icons-sorted-by-name-in-launchpad), and I'm afraid the answer is that it's a bug that has been reported to Apple.